# SQL BETWEEN return empty rows even if value exist

Tags: sql, between

what am I doing wrong with my sql query? It always return an empty rows even if there is a value exist.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  user_theme_id IN ( 9735, 9325, 4128 ) 
       AND ( user_date_created BETWEEN '2013-06-04' AND '2013-06-10' );
```

I tried to cut my original query one by one, I got a result. Here is the first one:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_theme_id IN (9735, 9325, 4128 );
```

I got 3 rows for this result. See attached snapshot:
[image]

Now, the next query that I run is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  user_date_created BETWEEN '2013-06-04' AND '2013-06-10';
```

I do get 3 results on this. See attached snapshot:
[image]

By the way, this sql that uses BETWEEN should suppose return 4 rows  but it only return 3. It doesn't return the data which has the created date of  2013-06-10 08:27:43

What am I doing wrong with my original query Why does it always return an empty rows?

Comment: Maybe because the 3 rows that your first query gives you are different from the ones the second query gives you?

Comment: Nope, they are the same.

Comment: Can you please post your data? I don't believe that the data is the same... it's how SQL works.

Comment: Agree with Ben. Post the results you get with 2 where clauses.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1a45/1) of how your data could be, each of the two queries with only one where clause returns 3 results, combined returns none.

Comment: Yes created date is of DateTime type

Comment: My guess would be that because you're not explicitly converting to a date it's being implicitly converted to a character in a a different manner than you think. You don't mention what RDBMS you're using but convert your date strings to a date when comparing. If your RDBMS supports ANSI date literals then you could do it like this, for instance: `WHERE  user_date_created BETWEEN date '2013-06-04' AND date '2013-06-10'`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting results by separately running different where clauses doesn't guarantee that `AND` 2 `where` clauses will **return** an answer.
There has to be **intersection** of rows to get result while `AND`.
You should **validate** your data and see if **overlapping** exists.

Answer (score 1):

I have able to make it work by not using the SQL `BETWEEN` operators but instead `COMPARISON` OPERATORS like: `>= || <=`

I have read it from **[W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)**, the SQL between can produce different results in different databases.

This is the content:

```
Notice that the BETWEEN operator can produce different result in different databases!
In some databases, BETWEEN selects fields that are between and excluding the test values.
In other databases, BETWEEN selects fields that are between and including the test values.
And in other databases, BETWEEN selects fields between the test values, including the first test value and excluding the last test value.

Therefore: Check how your database treats the BETWEEN operator!
```

That is what happened in the issue that I am facing. The first field was being treated as part of the test values and the 2nd field was being excluded. Using the comparison operators give accurate result.